# Background image works in live server, but doesn't work in Xamp

Tags: php, html, css, xampp, background-image

[Here is a picture of my file paths.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mI6Dt.png)I'm making a personal Portfolio page for a class assignment, 90% of the work was done using VSCode liveserver to check my progress, however i needed to add php to handle my forms, I started viewing my site using xammp to track my progress with the database. However before i could get to that my background image refuses to load. I've checked the url path over and over and i cant see the problem.

```css
//code that works while using liveserver 
.banner-wrap {
    background: url(/imgs/caspar-camille-rubin-fPkvU7RDmCo-unsplash.jpg) no-repeat center center/cover;
      z-index: 0;
} 

//code that SHOULD work in xammp 
.banner-wrap{
    background: url('../imgs/caspar-camille-rubin-fPkvU7RDmCo-unsplash.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Comment: When in doubt, use the full URL if that full URL loads in the browser. Otherwise, check if the root is correct, to let the relative path work as well.

Comment: When i pasted the full url, the web browser was able to access the picture on xaamp. I'm starting to think the url path isn't the problem, but im lost on what to do with that.

Comment: what is your folder structure? where is this css code in relation to the `imgs` folder?   the leading `/` starts from the website root.  The leading `../` starts from the parent of the folder where this css resides.  No leading anything starts from the folder where this css resides so `'imgs/caspar...` would mean the `imgs` folder is a child of the folder where this css resides.  [relative paths source](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Comment: Im not able to post pictures in comments so I'll update the post with a pic of my file paths. thanks in advance for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

OP here, so I've solved the issue, but i have no idea why it's working now. All i did was open Chrome Developer tools and post the same file path from my css into the chrome developer css,  reload the page and the background was there. From then on the file path in my css seems to work as intended without me changing a line of code in my files. If anyone knows why this solution works please let me know. Very satisfied with the results, equally confused